# WCF Ria services and Visual Studio 2010 RC?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-3.0, wcf-ria-services

does anyone know what the planning is for WCF Ria services now that the RC of VS 2010 is out?
Specifically, when is a new build coming and will it be usable with Silverlight 3 now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To come back on my own question, Tim Heuer wrote a blog post about it [here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/02/09/faq-silverlight-and-visual-studio-2010-release-candidate.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+timheuer/riaservices+(Tim+Heuer+-+.NET+RIA+Services)).

In short, no support until next interim build of SL 4 / Ria services. No date available yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is answered in [Scott's Blog Post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/08/vs-2010-net-4-release-candidate.aspx)

Checkout known issues and Comments.

Comment: He only talkes about SL 3, not Ria services. There are a few questions in the comments, but no answer yet...